# Can more than a single modem (same model) connect in a Windows XP system?

Tags: networking, windows-xp, modem

I want to connect the 2 (2 or more) modems (same modems) in a Windows XP laptop.  Through the modems I want to use network at the same time.

Comment: This should be on superuser, not stackoverflow. Unless, that is, you're looking to write drivers and software to accomplish that if it can't be done out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

What sort of modems?  How are they connected to the computer?

If they are connected through Ethernet, you should be able to use two modems, but the configuration would not be easy, and would depend on how you want to use the different connections.  It's not possible to say anything more about that with the lack of information from you.

If they connect through USB, I doubt you will be able to use them both at the same time.  As you are using a laptop, I suspect you want to use USB modems.